# Untrusted SSL certificate - Custom keystore issues

Tags: android, ssl

I have my own PKI infrastructure for my web server with a CA and an intermediate CA. Then I have a web certificate signed by the intermediate CA and I want my app to communicate with the server. According to [the Developer docs](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa) the solution is to create my own keystore. So I bundled the root CA certificate with the app and tried to see if that would work. It didnt, and I got the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

So my question is this. Since the SSL certificate is signed by my intermediate CA, is that the certificate I should be importing into the custom key store, or do I need both, or is there something else wrong here?

Ultimately, with a SSL certificate signed by a CA not trusted by Android, is this the right way to go about it?

Thanks!

Here's the code that sets up the keystore manager.

```
public SSLContext getTrusted() throws Exception{
        // Load CAs from an InputStream
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        AssetManager assManager = context.getAssets();
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
                is = assManager.open("ca.cert.crt");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        Certificate ca;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            Log.d("TrustMan", "ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }

        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);


        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return context;
    }
```

And then I am trying to use it as follows.

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
TrustMan tm = new TrustMan(context);
SSLContext sslContext;
sslContext = tm.getTrusted();

connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

Comment: Off the cuff, my guess is that you need both the intermediate CA and the root CA in your custom `TrustStore`.

Comment: @jww Ive added the code. I have tried adding the root CA certificate which didnt work.. Tried adding the intermediate CA certificate which didnt work and I also tried adding only the web certificate which didnt work either

Answer (score 1):

The code did actually work, but not when I returned the SSLContext from my class. I adjusted the class to return the TrustManagerFactory instead, and using the intermediate CA certificate works fine now!

Thanks!

Comment: Any required intermediate certificates should be sent by the server. Its not the client's job to locate a missing one. The client does not know where to go for a missing intermediate. Its known as the "which directory" problem in PKI. Its a well known problem.